# T-SQL - calculate percentage where denominator is all rows for a specific date

Tags: t-sql, subquery, percentage

I am trying to create columns to show percentages for each row where the denominator is the total for all rows in a given year.

Currently the query I have created looks like this:

```
    SELECT
   pend,
   ReportingPeriod,
   Area,
   SubsCategoryId,
   gender,
   age_group,
   Ethnicity,
   AllInTx_Count,
   NewTx_Count
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         p.pend,
         ReportingPeriod,
         p.Area,
         SubsCategoryId,
         gender,
         age_group,
         Ethnicity,
         AllInTx AS AllInTx_Count,
         NewTx AS NewTx_Count
      FROM
         (
            SELECT
               pend,
               Area,
               CONVERT(char(4), DATEPART(yy, pend) - 1) + '/' + RIGHT(CONVERT(char(4), DATEPART(yy, pend)), 2) AS ReportingPeriod,
               SubsCategoryId,
               gender,
               age_group,
               'White' AS Ethnicity,
               SUM(Eth_White_NewTx) AS NewTx,
               SUM(Eth_White_AllInTx) AS AllInTx 
            FROM
               dbo.ViewIt_Main 
            GROUP BY
               pend,
               Area,
               SubsCategoryId,
               gender,
               age_group 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
               pend,
               Area,
               CONVERT(char(4), DATEPART(yy, pend) - 1) + '/' + RIGHT(CONVERT(char(4), DATEPART(yy, pend)), 2) AS ReportingPeriod,
               SubsCategoryId,
               gender,
               age_group,
               'Mixed/Multiple ethnic group' AS Ethnicity,
               SUM(Eth_Mixed_NewTx) AS NewTx,
               SUM(Eth_Mixed_AllInTx) AS AllInTx 
            FROM
               dbo.ViewIt_Main AS ViewIt_Main_5 
            GROUP BY
               pend,
               Area,
               SubsCategoryId,
               gender,
               age_group 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
               pend,
               Area,
               CONVERT(char(4), DATEPART(yy, pend) - 1) + '/' + RIGHT(CONVERT(char(4), DATEPART(yy, pend)), 2) AS ReportingPeriod,
               SubsCategoryId,
               gender,
               age_group,
               'Asian/Asian British' AS Ethnicity,
               SUM(Eth_Asian_NewTx) AS NewTx,
               SUM(Eth_Asian_AllInTx) AS AllInTx 
            FROM
               dbo.ViewIt_Main AS ViewIt_Main_4 
            GROUP BY
               pend,
               Area,
               SubsCategoryId,
               gender,
               age_group 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
               pend,
               Area,
               CONVERT(char(4), DATEPART(yy, pend) - 1) + '/' + RIGHT(CONVERT(char(4), DATEPART(yy, pend)), 2) AS ReportingPeriod,
               SubsCategoryId,
               gender,
               age_group,
               'Black/African/Caribbean/Black British' AS Ethnicity,
               SUM(Eth_Black_NewTx) AS NewTx,
               SUM(Eth_Black_AllInTx) AS AllInTx 
            FROM
               dbo.ViewIt_Main AS ViewIt_Main_3 
            GROUP BY
               pend,
               Area,
               SubsCategoryId,
               gender,
               age_group 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
               pend,
               Area,
               CONVERT(char(4), DATEPART(yy, pend) - 1) + '/' + RIGHT(CONVERT(char(4), DATEPART(yy, pend)), 2) AS ReportingPeriod,
               SubsCategoryId,
               gender,
               age_group,
               'Other ethnic group' AS Ethnicity,
               SUM(Eth_Other_NewTx) AS NewTx,
               SUM(Eth_Other_AllInTx) AS AllInTx 
            FROM
               dbo.ViewIt_Main AS ViewIt_Main_2 
            GROUP BY
               pend,
               Area,
               SubsCategoryId,
               gender,
               age_group
         )
         AS p 
   )
   AS f
```

Below is a screenshot showing the current output of this query:

[image]

I need the denominator to be the sum of all Ethnicities in a given pend for the SubsCategoryId, Area, gender and age_group.

Like current output I need to create two columns one for the proportion of AllInTx and another for NewTx.

How do I modify the query to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain you can solve your problem here by unpivoting your data using a `cross apply values` and then calculating your proportional values through window functions, which results in a much simpler query statement:

```
SELECT
    pend,
    ReportingPeriod,
    Area,
    SubsCategoryId,
    gender,
    age_group,
    Ethnicity,
    NewTx,
    AllInTx,    -- ISNULL(NULLIF( combo catches divide by 0 errors
    ISNULL(CAST(NewTx   AS DECIMAL(19,4)) / NULLIF(SUM(NewTx) OVER (PARTITION BY pend,Area,SubsCategoryId,gender,age_group),0),0) as NewTxProportion,
    ISNULL(CAST(AllInTx AS DECIMAL(19,4)) / NULLIF(SUM(AllInTx) OVER (PARTITION BY pend,Area,SubsCategoryId,gender,age_group),0),0) as AllInTxProportion,
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        m.pend,
        CONVERT(char(4), DATEPART(yy, m.pend) - 1) + '/' + RIGHT(CONVERT(char(4), DATEPART(yy, m.pend)), 2) AS ReportingPeriod,
        m.Area,
        m.SubsCategoryId,
        m.gender,
        m.age_group,
        e.Ethnicity,
        SUM(e.NewTx) AS NewTx,
        SUM(e.AllInTx) AS AllInTx 
    FROM dbo.ViewIt_Main as m
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES('White'                                 ,m.Eth_White_NewTx, m.Eth_White_AllInTx)
                          ,('Mixed/Multiple ethnic group'           ,m.Eth_Mixed_NewTx, m.Eth_Mixed_AllInTx)
                          ,('Asian/Asian British'                   ,m.Eth_Asian_NewTx, m.Eth_Asian_AllInTx)
                          ,('Black/African/Caribbean/Black British' ,m.Eth_Black_NewTx, m.Eth_Black_AllInTx)
                          ,('Other ethnic group'                    ,m.Eth_Other_NewTx, m.Eth_Other_AllInTx)
                    ) as e(Ethnicity
                          ,NewTx
                          ,AllInTx
                          )
    GROUP BY
        m.pend,
        m.Area,
        m.SubsCategoryId,
        m.gender,
        m.age_group,
        e.Ethnicity
) as d;
```